# TypeError: db.query is not a function & Error: Failure when receiving data from the peer

Tags: typescript, express

so this is a user database modle, and i'm using express typescript but when i test it using insomnia i get the error "Error: Failure when receiving data from the peer" and at the same time i get this error in the vscode terminal TypeError: db.query is not a function, also i looked up similar issues and i found alot of threads talking about callback list now i didn't know what whas these and looked them up, and used some help of google bard but got know where if anyone can help even by taking the first function and implementing a call back list and explain i'd appreciate it, also i'm new to this it's my first time writing a fully functional backend with db, so i really need the help.

```
const db = require("../config/database");

async function getusers(){
    try {
        const [rows] = await db.query("SELECT * FROM users");
        return rows; // Return the retrieved rows
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error fetching users:', err);
            throw err; // Rethrow the error to handle it elsewhere if needed
        }
};

// fetching users
    export const users = async () => {
     return await getusers();
 };

async function createUser(username: any, email:any, password: any) {
    try {
        const query: string  ="INSERT INTO users WHERE username = ? email = ? password =? "
        const values = [username, email, password]
        const user  = await db.query(query, values);
        return user[0];
    } catch (err) {
        throw err
        console.log("Error creating a new user: ", err);
    };
};


async function get_user_by_ID(id: number) {
    try {
    const query: string = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?";
    const values = [id];
    const [rows] = await db.query(query, values); // db.query function is now explicitly typed to return an array of RowDataPacket objects
    return rows[0]; // Return the retrieved rows
    } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error fetching users by ID:', err);
    throw err; // Rethrow the error to handle it elsewhere if needed
    }
    };

async function deleteUser(id:number){
    // code for deleting user goes here
        try {
            const query: string = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = ?"
            const values = [id];
            const [rows] = await db.query(query, values);
            return rows[0]; 
    
        } catch (err) {
            console.log
        };
    }
```